# JavaScript garbage collection when variable goes out of scope

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Does JavaScript support garbage collection?

For example, if I use:

```
function sayHello (name){
    var myName = name;
    alert(myName);
}
```

do I need to use "delete" to delete the `myName` variable or I just ignore it?

Comment: certainly no, CTO:  http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-157637.html

Comment: Please retag/retitle: this has nothing to do with optimization. I suggest "JavaScript variable scope"

Comment: See also this question about the JS GC - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore it - after the sayHello function completes, myName falls out-of-scope and gets gc'ed.

Answer (score 7):

no.
`delete` is used to remove properties from objects, not for memory management.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript supports garbage collection. In this case, since you explicitly declare the variable within the function, it will (1) go out of scope when the function exits and be collected sometime after that, and (2) cannot be the target of `delete` (per reference linked below).

Where `delete` may be useful is if you declare variables implicitly, which puts them in global scope:

```
function foo()
{
    x = "foo";   /* x is in global scope */
    delete x;
}
```

However, it's a bad practice to define variables implicitly, so always use `var` and you won't have to care about `delete`.

For more information, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything Ted, no need to delete this variable.

Refer: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-157637.html

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, when the function exits then your variable falls out of scope, as it's scope is just within the function, so the gc can then clean it up.

But, it is possible for that variable to be referenced by something outside the function, then it won't be gc'ed for a while, if ever, as it is still has a reference to it.

You may want to read up on scoping in javascript:
http://www.webdotdev.com/nvd/content/view/1340/

With closures you can create memory leaks, which may be the problem you are trying to deal with, and is related to the problem I had mentioned:
http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html