# Memory leak when transferring image data to Web Worker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, memory-leaks, web-worker

I'm repeatedly passing image data from an HTML5 `canvas` to a Web Worker using a [Transferrable Object](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast) --

Condensed Code:

```
var worker = new Worker("test.js");
setInterval(function () {
    var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    worker.webkitPostMessage(data, [data]);
}, 100);
```

The problem is that memory usage increases astronomically every few seconds and doesn't appear to decrease when the function isn't being called. For cases in which the memory usage exceeds a certain threshold, chrome will actually crash as a result of this leak. I would welcome any and  all suggestions, including alternative methods for sending data to the Web Worker. Many thanks!

Comment: Chrome will leak memory even when the worker does nothing on the `onmessage` event.

Comment: I think I understand how that might work, but could you provide a brief code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it is not about web workers.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

setInterval(function () {
  var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}, 100);
```

This code I think provides the same memory leak. Also I've found this issues:

1. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51171
2. [JavaScript memory problem with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745861/javascript-memory-problem-with-canvas)