# Garbage Collection and JavaScript "delete": Is this overkill/obfuscation, or a good practice?

Tags: javascript, object, memory, garbage-collection

I just read this question and the accepted answer:  [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

In the answer, [Noldorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44389/noldorin) referenced some guidelines from Apple.  Here is the part I'm concerned with:

> Use delete statements. Whenever you create an object using a new statement, pair it with a delete statement. This ensures that all of the memory associated with the object, including its property name, is available for garbage collection.

I'm always taking time to keep up-to-speed on best practices, especially if I can reduce the memory footprint of my scripts.  So I went off to test some things.  If I understand correctly, the following is an example of an object that deletes itself after invoking a method.

```
var thing = function () {
    var a_method, and_another;
    a_method    = function() { /* do stuff */ };
    and_another = function() { /* do some other stuff*/ };
    this.init   = function() { a_method(); and_another(); };
};
delete new thing().init();
```

Usually I'll wrap everything in a self invoking function and pass in my globals just like above.  Everything is the same as I would normally do it, the only difference being that I added the `delete` right before the `new`.

The code works either way.

So the question is:  Am I doing *anything* here?  Is there some kind of benefit to deleting a reference to an object that only exists inside a function scope?  Or am I just making things look confusing?

Comment: I stopped doing garbage collection like ten years ago :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First of all the statement `delete new scoped_object().init();` is not really doing anything, you should better take care about what variables remain in-closure or if you have circular references, which are the most common source of [memory leaks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/).

The `delete` operator is meant to be used to *delete object properties*, and it is **really** misunderstood, the answer you quote from @Noldorin quotes some text of the [Apple JavaScript "Best Practices"](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/ScriptingAutomation/Conceptual/JSCodingGuide/Advanced/Advanced.html), but *they don't have a clue* about how `delete` works!!.

They even recommend using `delete` on variable references, and that is not possible -only possible for variables declared in *Eval Code*-, because the `var` statement declares the variable as non-deletable (`{DontDelete}` in ECMAScript 3, or `[[Configurable]] = false` in ECMAScript 5) properties of the Variable Object -objects that form the scope chain-.

Moreover, attempting to `delete` a reference to an identifier that is bound to an environment record - an identifier declared with a `VariableDeclaration`, `FunctionDeclaration` or from a function's `FormalParameterList`-, causes a `SyntaxError` exception on the new [ECMAScript 5th Edition](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.4.1) under [Strict Mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/).

I would recommend you to read the following article about `delete`:

- [Understanding `delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: The link "Understanding delete" is broken (due to an extra slash at the end). The link is [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete)