# Is using the Js delete operator to remove a property from an object considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript

When removing a property from an object, I've used the `delete` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) in the past. But when I had my code reviewed by a person with a CS background, they wanted me to find another way of removing the property because it was an "expensive" task (not sure what that means). Since I'm self taught I wanted to ask if **deleting in Js is something I should consider using as last resort?** I've looked at other responses within SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript) but couldn't find anything that makes reference to this.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to delete properties, you probably want to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Another possibility is that you might want to explore another approach entirely to the problem you're trying to solve, one that is expressed more naturally in JavaScript.

Comment: Expensive means it requires more computing processes and takes a longer time to execute the code. I don't know if it's true or not, but even if it's expensive, I'm sure our machines can easily delete some keys..

Comment: @BülentAkgül thanks for that tidbit of information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not considered bad practice. It just depends on what you want to do,

Read this thread:
[Garbage Collection and JavaScript "delete": Is this overkill/obfuscation, or a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788805/garbage-collection-and-javascript-delete-is-this-overkill-obfuscation-or-a-g)

Answer (score 2):

The book "JavaScript, the Good Parts" by Douglas CrockFord says...

> The delete operator can be used to remove a property from an object. It will remove a property from the object if it has one. It will not touch any of the objects in the proto-
> type linkage.

I think you can use the `Delete` operator without worries. There are many other ways to remove a property from an object, but all they are more expensive in my opinion.