# How to convert from object from interface A to interface B by deleting property

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have two interfaces:

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  x: string;
}

interface B {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

When I have an object implementing interface `A` and I want to drop the property `x` (and the object implements interface `B` afterwards) - how do I tell TS what I am trying to do? Just executing `delete obj.x;` on the object causes TS to complain, because `x` is required from interface `A`.

Comment: What do you mean by `convert`? Interfaces are just shapes.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmQGcwpQBzAbh2QCNCSyQqaAPB0i6gXyy1EixEKAEKYaBYp2bVc9KUxa8ANhDB5khdAF5MeQgCJgBgDR1DAa1PJ2yAwBN7B5N2qr1tTcjG641IA

Comment: This is a strange example. Any object that is a valid `A` is also a valid `B`. No conversion is necessary.

Comment: I want to remove the property `x` from the object. TS don't want me to, because interface A says the prop should be there.

Comment: I updated the wording of the question to be clearer. I want to remove property `x` from the object.

Comment: `delete (obj as any).x;` will make the compiler happy. Not so pretty but it works.

Comment: Perhaps something like this would suit your needs: `const convert = (a: A): B => { const {x, ...b} = a; return b };`

Comment: Okay, both suggestions are... ugly :D
I think I'll go with the idea of Christian - the answer of CRice will expand to a lot more "real" javascript code after compilation.

Comment: Fair enough, but do note that a destructuring assignment is an ES6 feature and TypeScript will not transform that code if your target is ES6 or higher.

Comment: I am working with a lot of code at work that still needs to work in IE11, so I try to train my brain to rely on patterns that require fewer polyfills and generate less code after compilation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd have done that.

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  x: string;
}

interface B {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

function convertAtoB(a: A) {
  delete (a as any).x;
  return a as B;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this throws a typescript error ‍♂️

Comment: Using type casting is a hack in this case

Comment: Corrected, it now works. Using `as` should be exceptional since it could generate type errors, and that's precisely the reason why TS exists, but here it's totally safe to use since everything around the `as` statements is type-guarded.

Comment: Yup, the `delete (a as any).x` did the trick, like Christian already mentioned in the comment above. I updated the code a little and marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for editing, it's way better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Omit` or make property an optional

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  x: string;
}

interface A1 {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  x?: string;

}

const result: Omit<A, 'x'> = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
const result1: A1 = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```

It is considered a bad practive to use `delete`.

Please consider next type safe example to remove object property

```js
const removeProperty = <T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: P): Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, P>> => {
  const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest
}

const result2 = removeProperty({ age: 2, name: 'John' }, 'name') // { age: 2 }
```

Comment: No, using `delete` is not a bad practise at all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64581530/13230118

Comment: @a2br You should use `Reflect.deleteProperty()` instead of `delete`

Comment: How would using delete be a bad practice? A reference to a source for that statement would be cool.

Comment: According to MDN, `Reflect.deleteProperty()` works just like `delete`

Comment: Yeah, with the only difference that its "new shit" that IE11 does not understand. delete worked since... forever?

Comment: `delete` operator has performance negative effects for the V8 hidden classes pattern

Comment: Okay, well. This is a rather esoteric issue. Also readability & understandability > performance. You have to try really hard to make V8 slow.