# document.getElementbyID vs. variable declaration and delete performance

Tags: javascript, performance, cordova

I would like to know what is more appropriate to do if I really need a good performance for my app. I'm programming cross-platform apps via PhoneGap and the way I code is very crucial.

Which is more appropriate:

```
document.getElementbyID('id').addEventListener()
```

or

```
var id = document.getElementbyID('id');
id.addEventListener();
```

and how can I use the keyword "delete" to improve the performance of my app?

Comment: It doesn't matter performance-wise. *Maybe* there is a microscopic difference if you do this for tens of thousands of elements at once, but that isn't the case is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the two will be marginal. To improve performance you should minimize the number  of event handlers you add to the dom and remove those you don't require again. Delete doesn't make sense in the context you posted. It should be used to free up items in (associative) arrays or to remove objects you created. You do neither of those in your example.

For lists in which each item is clickable you should just attach one event handler to the list container and not to individual elements. You can then use the target property of the event object passed into the handler to find the actual listitem that was tapped.

---

**edit: an example on how to use one event handler for multiple list items**

The li.id is used to identify the actual item that was clicked. If the 'li' have children you might have to walk up the target DOM tree until you find the correct item.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item_1">First Item</li>
    <li id="item_2">Second Item</li>
    <li id="item_3">Third Item</li>
    <li id="item_4">Fourth Item</li>
    <li id="item_5">Fifth Item</li>
    <li id="item_6">Sixth Item</li>
    <li id="item_7">Seventh Item</li>
</ul>

<script>
    window.onload(function() {
        document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", 
            function(event) { alert("" + event.target.id + " was clicked"); });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi! sorry for the noob question but can u show me an example of using the "target" property method u suggested. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid-vs-variable-declaration) i just made on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com), `document.getElementbyID('id').addEventListener()` seems to be the fastest way. - in Chrome on Mac OS X.

[Try it](http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid-vs-variable-declaration) on the desired browsers, and edit the test to add/remove features such as the `delete` you were talking about.

[image: JSPerf test results]

Comment: It looks like jsperf may have got a bit confused. Higher ops/sec means better performance (and it even points out that the "slowest" test was -123% (note that it's a negative number) slower...) So actually, the `var` test was quickest.

Comment: ok now i'm confused haha! Which is faster? The red indication really shows that the latter is faster. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: +1 for suggesting a cool tool...However I got very different results even between tests a few seconds apart in the same browser (plus I noticed the discrepancies that @JamesAllardice pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is interpreted at runtime, so ultimately it depends on whether or not the compiler optimizes away that variable allocation or not. Either way, the difference will be extremely small. Build a few tests and see.

Focus on readability (and finding a model where you are not worried about micro-optimization).

> and how can i use the keyword "delete" to improve the performance of
>   my app?

Since you are discussing performance-intensive applications, I assume you are interested in proper garbage collection in JavaScript. See [How does garbage collection work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324133/javascript-garbage-collection)

Comment: `delete` is used to delete object properties. For example `var x = {y: 1}; delete x.y;`

Comment: @JamesAllardice - yes, just looked that up for my own sake...edited my post to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use

```
var id = document.getElementbyID('id');
id.addEventListener();
```

If you require the DOM element more than once else it takes same time for both ways.

Comment: By using variable you prevent multiple traversing of document for same element.