# Reusing Google Maps in a cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, google-maps

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282395/reuse-instance-of-google-maps-api-on-single-page-application) but I could not find an answer for my case. I have a Cordova jQuery mobile app. One of the app pages has a google map which I have to initialize every time I load the page. I am doing something like this

```
var canvas = $('#journey_map_canvas')[0];
tripOptions.journeyMap = new google.maps.Map(canvas, tripOptions.journeyMapOptions);
```

After this I plot a route using polyline. On the page container hide event I remove the route but keep the previous map.

```
function unplotRoute() {
   for (var i = 0; i < tripDetailsObject.segmentLine.length; i++) {
      tripDetailsObject.segmentLine[i].setMap(null);
   }
   tripDetailsObject.segmentLine = [];
}
```

Instead of initializing this map when the page is loaded I want to reuse it but I don't know how to do that. I have the map saved in `tripOptions.journeyMap` object and I have checked that it this object still exists on page unload. But if I do not reinitialize this object and attach it to the the canvas it doesn't get attached to the canvas element of the DOM.

Comment: Is there a way to simply append the map to the html element.

Comment: can anyone help me with this?