# Do I need remove google maps objects after creating them?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

My app lets users create and remove input fields, on the creation of each input field I run

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Then, when my users remove the input fields later, I remove the dom element class=".pac-container" created by google autocomplete

```
document.body.removeChild( thePacContainers[i] );
```

My question: **is there an object created by new google.maps still floating in memory that I need to remove?** I'm not worried about the event listeneres on the input field, as the input fields are removed from the dom and I *think* modern browsers manage removing their event handlers.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485582/what-is-the-proper-way-to-destroy-a-map-instance

Comment: Yeah, I think I should refactor my application to just show and hide an existing block of map instances.