# uxNotification. How to destroy a notification window?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I use `uxNotification` plugin in my application. In the sourcecode I configured it with a property `destroyAfterHide` set to `true` and added additional property `closeAction` set to `destroy`. However, after I click on the close button and do `win.destroy()` manually, alert(win) still shows an object, but not `undefined` or `null` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/AbstractComponent.html#Ext-AbstractComponent-method-destroy) at what the `destroy` function actually does.  Essentially, it cleans up all of the references to the object that ExtJS created so that it can be garbage collected.  If you have any of your own references to the object (the `win` variable in your case), it can't be garbage collected yet.  What you should see, however, is that ExtJS has deemed the object destroyed.

```
alert(win.destroyed); //should alert 'true'
```

Then, once your `win` variable is no longer reachable, it will be picked up by the GC.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324133/javascript-garbage-collection) for an explanation on how GC works in JavaScript.  If you don't want to wait for the GC you can reassign the variable:

```
win = undefined; //or win = null;
```