# What do JavaScript objects outlast and when are they destroyed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui

I'm quite new to Javascript and I was just reading following article.

> you can define an ajax connection
>   once, and reuse it multiple times, and
>   start and stop it later on. Here's an
>   example:

```
var myAjaxRequest = A.io.request('test.html', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      key1: 'value1'
    }
});
```

> Now later on, if I want to make that
>   same ajax call again, all I have to do
>   is call:

```
myAjaxRequest.start();
```

What if I had a very frequently used auction page and I wanted to use the myAjaxRequest connection for all actions a user does from his browser. What are the rules for lifetime of the myAjaxRequest instance ? I suppose it is destroyed on page refresh. But is it anything else that destroys it ? Let say that the object is created within YUI sandbox, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: No. If you don't change the `myAjaxRequest` object manually, it will be available for the lifetime of the document. (assuming that the variable is a global variable)

Comment: Set myAjaxRequest = null. It should do gc sometime depends on browser.

Comment: And what about time, browser memory management or something. I think in this case the variable is within a scope of a callback function of YUI sandbox. It loads an instance of a module for this variable. But let suppose it's a global variable..

Comment: You can read this link for more info about gc in javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection

Comment: Ok, thank you guys, I think I got it

Comment: So why aren't any of these _answers_ actual answers instead of just comments? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a shame this was answered in comments because nobody gets closure (sorry, terrible pun). @Šime Vidas and @WaiLam deserve the credit but I will at least attempt to craft an answer:

While you have a reference to the object (though the variable `myAjaxRequest`) it will remain in memory until the document is unloaded. If you assign null to your variable (`myAjaxRequest = null`), **and** there are no other references to the object, then the garbage collector will reclaim the memory used to store it.

A reference can exist even if `myAjaxRequest` is a local variable within a function. The function can return a reference to the local variable, for example as a object property e.g:

```
function sandbox () {
    var myAjaxRequest = A.io.request(/* constructor... */);

    return {
        myRequest: myAjaxRequest
    };
}

var mySandbox = sandbox();
mySandbox.myRequest.start();
```

or it can return a reference through a closure ([excellent explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200)), e.g:

```
function sandbox () {
    var myAjaxRequest = A.io.request(/* constructor... */);

    return {
        getRequest: function () {
            return myAjaxRequest;
        } 
    };
}

var mySandbox = sandbox();
mySandbox.getRequest().start();
```

As long as you have a reference to your object it will not be garbage collected. You can safely call the `start` method until the page is unloaded.