# What happens to the memory used by a function when it is removed

Tags: javascript, function, memory-management

If I have a self-destroying function

```
function tempFunc() {
   //do some stuff, then...

   tempFunc = function() {return;}
}
```

or

```
function tempFunc() {
   //do some stuff, then...

   delete tempFunc;
}
```

What happens to the original code of tempFunc? Is it held in memory anywhere? How is the situation changed if the function leaves behind something a bit more permanent e.g. creates an object which has access to variables contained within the function's closure.

Comment: I don't think javascript (or ECMA script) specifies how memory is reclaimed, if at all. Most probably, your implementations keeps tabs on what's reachable and does a garbage collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are no more referenced to the function, it can be garbage-collected.

If there are referenced through closures, it can't.

Comment: In addition : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection :)