# What is object lifetime in javascript code that uses prototype inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am currently reading 'Javascript Good Parts', and I came across the following paragraph

> If we try to retrieve a property value from an object, and if the
>   object lacks the property name, then JavaScript attempts to retrieve
>   the property value from the prototype object. And if that object is
>   lacking the property, then it goes to its prototype, and so on until
>   the process finally bottoms out with Object.prototype.

If I create an object obj2 from obj1 as prototype, does that mean obj1 cannot be destroyed until obj2 also goes out of scope?

Comment: I really don't know how different JavaScript engines implement prototype, but I don't think it's like a **reference** to an object. It's more like an inheritance mechanism, so I would be surprised if an **instance** of obj1 is needed for obj2 to exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you've built your object's inheritance (linked the prototypes), I don't think that the browser relies on your references to that object.

**ex1 :**

```
var a = function(){};
a.prototype.toString = function(){return "I'm an A!";};
var b = new a();
a = undefined;
var c = new a();// error => a is not a function any more!
b.toString();// it works because the prototype is not destroyed, 
             // only our reference is destroyed
```

**ex2 :**

```
var a = function(){};
a.prototype.toString = function(){return "I'm an A!";};
var b = function(){};
b.prototype = new a();
a = undefined;
var c = new b();
console.log(c+'');// It still works, although our 
                  // initial prototype `a` doesn't exist any more.
```

**UPDATE:**
This behaviour might be related to the fact that in javascript you can't exactly destroy an object; you can only remove all references to it. After that, the browser decides how to deal with the unreferenced objects through it's [Garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection).

Comment: Hm, wasn't `a` just a reference to that object, just like `b.prototype` is? Seems like we still have a reference.

Comment: `b.prototype` is an **instance** of `a`. (feel the `new` keyword)

Comment: As a **name** `b.prototype` is certainly a **reference**, `new a()` returnes an unnamed reference to an object, which could be assigned to a named reference, like `b.prototype`, or could be used once and after been used that way it becomes inaccessible (literally goes out of scope).