# garbage collection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Consider this multi-level nested JavaScript object.

```
function foo() {
    var channels = {
        2: {
            name: "station 1", 
            description: "station1",
            img: ["img1-a", "img1-b", "img1-c"]
        },
        3: {
            name: "station 2", 
            description: "station2",
            img: ["img2-a", "img2-b", "img2-c"]
        },
        4: {
            name: "station 3", 
            description: "station3",
            img: ["img3-a", "img3-b", "img3-c"]
        },
    };

    console.log(channels);          
};          
....                
// calling foo.
foo();
```

After the function `foo()` returns, will all the nested objects (i.e. the individual channel objects, strings, the array *img*, and the strings in *img* array, all be automatically garbage collected ?

Or, do I need to explicitly iterate through and "delete" each object?

Comment: There is no reference to any of those objects/arrays anymore, so they will be garbage collected eventually.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection

Comment: @j08691 thanks for providing a great reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what happens in `console.log`. Certainly in Chrome, a reference to the `channels` object is kept in the console, so `channels` cannot be GC'd.

When you remove `console.log`, the full `channel` object will properly be GC'd, because there are no other references to it.

Comment: thanks for additional clarity. I didn't think of the console.log. So, if I were to keep a reference to the above object "channels" in a closure, I assume that, the memory will be garbage collected as soon as the reference to the _closure_ is released ? Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

They're eligible for GC as long as nothing else is referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

They should be, yes, because there is no more reference to that `channels` object nor the closure that contains it.

GC is mostly dependent on the browser that implements it, though, so there's no guarantee it'll actually be done. `delete`ing each element is overkill, though.

Comment: thanks I went with Rob's answer, due to additional info on console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has its own garbage collector implemented by the browser's engine (v8 or whatever). You don't have to deallocate references. Once the root goes out of scope, they will all be eligible for gc.