# Will infinite scroll cause browser crashes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, crash

I implemented infinite scroll like so:

```
new_page_value = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200) {

        new_page_value = parseInt(new_page_value) + 1;

        get_page(new_page_value);

    }
});
```

When the user almost reaches the bottom of the page (200px left) the function `get_page()` is called. This contains an ajax call that gets all the contents of the new page and **appends** it to the `<body>` of the document.

Now I just realized if my site gets big and instead of having 10 small pages I have a gazillion giant pages then the user's browser might crash if they are persistent enough to keep infinite scrolling for long time.

Would this be a possible solution to this problem:

I will keep appending the new pages to the document `<body>` until the 10th page, after that I will be replacing the `<body>` content entirely instead of appending. So using `html()` rather than `append()`.

I just don't know if this will actually work to prevent crashes. Will `.html()` clear the "memory" of prior html that was brought in via ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really think this is a common issue for many sites with AJAX list content. So let's take an example at some of the most popular ( think of scale = experience ) websites and their solutions :

#### Google Images

If you check out [images.google.com](http://images.google.com) and you search for whatever, for e.g. "guiness", you will see a page full of results (actually the images are ajax loaded, not the html-code, so the page is with fixed height) and when you scroll at the bottom there is a button `"Show more results"`. This might be solution one of your problem, but is it really necessary to place a button at the bottom after, for e.g. the 10-th page? I really think it is generally a good solution for page usability and memory leaks, but it is really not a necessary option as we can see in :

#### Facebook

Facebook Newsfeed is another story. There is a button `"Show more posts"`, but I really don't know when exactly it is displayed rather than loading the next page of posts. It happened to me once to load 10-15 pages of posts, only by scrolling. And you know Facebook posts include videos, photos, AJAX comments and a lot of more Javascript fancy stuff, which take a lot of memory. I think they've managed to do this after a lot of research, how much of the users scroll to the bottom.

#### Youtube

Youtube has `"Load more videos"` at every page, so the solution is basically similar to Google, except that Google renders the whole html of the page and on scrolling just loads the images.

#### Twitter

Twitter supports infinite scrolling. Yep, they do it may be because tweet is 140 characters and they don't need to worry about memory so much. After all who is willing to read more than 1000 pages of tweets at one page load. So they don't have a button for `"load more"` and they don't need one.

So there are two solutions :

1. Use infinite scrolling ( you should consider how much content you load and how rich it is )
2. Use button : `"Load More"`

Most of all, you should not delete already loaded content of a list.

Nowadays everything is Javascript and Javascript has [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection), so it is very hard to unload the DOM ( if it has Javascript, not plain text ) and manage to remove the Garbage from Javascript. Which means that you won't free the whole allocated memory of the unloaded content from the browser.

Also think about of your requests, why would you need to load again something, that you have already loaded at first place. It costs another server request, meaning another database request and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with this before and here are some of my thoughts:

a) If you are appending data to the memory page(s) at a time then it is not an issue, some browsers might not respond well but most of the lastest browsers will render without any problem so long as there is enough memory on the target machine, you could probably see how the ram usage increases as you append pages. Use chrome for this as each page is a separate process and it has an inbuilt task manager

b) regarding usage of `html()`, it indeed removes the markup but it does so at a heavy cost as it tries to take care of special conditions and has an overhead and accesses all the controls nested within the container that you are replacing (not sure about the last pat), but it has a cost. A simpler way to clear the DOM would be to use the `innerHTML` property and set it to empty, jquery does this but it is at a later point in the `html()` api. open up the api and look at the method.
using `innerHTML`

`$("<selector>")[0].innerHTML=""`

Also deletion of pages sounds weird to me as a user, what if I want to go back to the initial comments and please dont think about making it an infinite scroller too.. I have tried and given up after the number of bugs raised but we had a genuine use case for it and I had to stick a button up there, but this wasnt when the user scrolled away from the first page, this is when the user landed on a 3rd page but now needs to see the results above it.

Hope that answers your question and btw infinte scrolling is your friend use it, dont over engineer a case which will probably only be tested by your QA team. Its better to spend your effort somewhere else.

Comment: `html()` behaves that way because failing to remove event handlers before taking nodes out of the DOM causes memory leaks. If you're going to circumvent this, track your own event handlers and clear them before touching `innerHTML`.

Comment: @eyelidlessness yup you are right.. But can you direct me to a resource where I can read abt this with examples probably

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will, if i may suggest an idea after let's say 5 pages just delete the first page and append the new one instead of deleted all of the previous pages. good luck :)