# How can I determine the source of excessive garbage collection in my HTML5 javascript game?

Tags: javascript, html, garbage-collection

How can I determine the source of excessive garbage collection in my HTML5 game?

Here's the result of a heap snapshot I took in chrome: [image: heap snapshot]

Comment: Example, please? How can we answer if you don't tell us anything that's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection Perhaps a relevant question you may look into? Having a good understanding of what garbage collection helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "excessive"? Too-frequent collection? Could you describe some symptoms to explain why you think your issue is related to garbage collection at all?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Sure -- looking at the memory timeline in Chrome shows the characteristic zigzag pattern of heavy garbage collection. Eventually, the garbage collection starts taking on the order of a second to complete, resulting in an unacceptable pause. Qiao essentially answered my question (hence the screenshot I posted), though I am hoping for more insight into the problem. For example, how can I get to the bottom of where all the Array objects are coming from? Is there some way to find out where they were created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome developer tools support the heap profiling. You may refer to https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling