# JavaScript memory usage management

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am building large website with heavy JavaScript usage, all of my content is being loaded trough `ajax`, it is very similar to Facebook, and since there is a lot of different pages I need a lot of JavaScript, so what I thought of is to divide my script in to sections, each page would have it's own script file.

Now loading is simple, I just load a new file with each page, but my concern is what will happen if user goes trough 100 different pages and load 100 different script files?

At the moment my website doesn't have that many pages, but I'm quite sure it will grow to nearly 100 unique pages at some point in the future.

So what would happen to the user with slower computer? I'm guessing it would start to slow down a lot since there would be no refresh. From what I have read it is impossible to just unload all events and data from loaded script file in any easy way, and if I were to try that it might cost me a way to much time and effort to do that.

So my question would be, should I just leave it the way it is or try to do something about it? I am currently using jQuery with few plugins, and if I had to guess average file would be around 50-200 lines of code with mostly `click` events, and `ajax` calls.

Note, each page objects has it's own prefix for each class, for example: `home_header`, `login_header`

So there shouldn't be any conflicts between `onClick` event listeners and similar things.

Comment: I would consider using a library like Backbone to organize it better, and you'll probably gain some performance by keeping things tidy. Can we see some of your code? Maybe optimization is the key here...

Comment: The site may well have 100+ pages but does it really have 100+ **types** of page? I doubt that even FB has that number of page types.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Well i was looking at the future, at the moment it will not have 100+ but im quite sure with time it will grow to that size

Comment: @elclanrs At the moment i don't that much script written, that's the reason why i'm asking for advice before i start most of my scripting

Comment: @Linas: Then yes, I'd say use a framework if it's a big app. Backbone, AngularJS, CanJS, Meteor, etc...check them all out and decide by yourself which one fits your workflow better.

Comment: Well, a general strategy for any page is to load javascript as follows : (i) libraries (jQuery etc), (ii) site-specific static data and utility functions, (iii) page-specific code. (i) and (ii) will be external .js files and (iii) may be an external .js file or served in `<script>...</script>` tags on the page, depending on the volume of code. Browsers will (generally) cache the external files.

Comment: If the ajax contents does not involve eventhooks and other sorts of scripts, U have nothing to worry about. If so - be sure to destroy listeners and datastores of sorts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because you are using AJAX doesn't automatically mean alarm bells with regards to memory usage... you should be more worried about the kind of things that cause memory leaks, and making sure you destruct as well as construct things properly:

- http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html
- http://nesj.net/blog/2012/04/javascript-memory-leaks/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/
- [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

As a rule, in any large system I tend to create a helper constructor that keeps track of all the items I may wish to destroy at a later date or on page unload *(event listeners, large attributes or object structures)* all indexed by a namespace. Then when I've finished with a particular section or entity I ask the helper system - I call it GarbageMonkey :) - to clear a particular namespace.

1. For events it unbinds
2. For attributes it unsets
3. For arrays / objects it scans and unsets each key and can do so for sub elements too
4. For elements it removes and cleans content as much as possible

Obviously for the above to work you need to be wary about leaving variables lying around that can keep a reference to the data you hope to delete. So this means being aware of what [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection) is, what [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) are; and how between them they can keep a variable alive forever!! ..or at least until the browser/tab is destroyed. It also means using object structures rather than vars because you can delete keys in any scope that has access to the object, but you cannot do so for vars.

So do this:

```
var data = {}, methods = {}, events = {};

methods.aTestMethod = function(){
  /// by assigning properties to an object, you can easily remove them later
  data.value1 = 123;
  data.value2 = 456;
  data.value3 = 789;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
var value1, value2, value3;

var aTestMethod = function(){
  value1 = 123;
  value2 = 456;
  value3 = 789;
}
```

The reason being because in the above you can later do this:

```
var i;
for( i in methods ){ delete methods[i]; }
for( i in data ){ delete data[i]; }
```

But you can't do this:

```
delete value1;
delete value2;
delete value3;
```

Now obviously the above wont protect you from a reference that points directly to a sub element of either `methods` or `data`. But if you only pass the `methods` and `data` objects around in your code, and keep tidy with regards to attaching methods as event listeners, then even if you do end up with a rogue reference it should only point to an empty object *(after you've deleted it's contents that is)*.

Answer (score 6):

If you recycle variables and don't pollute the global scope, you're on the right track; but as for your question, you should first find out if it is a practical concern.

This can be checked and monitored with a profiler - [out-of-the box Chrome is pretty decent for it](http://dev.chromium.org/memory-usage-backgrounder), just type `about:memory` in the URL and it'll give you a per-tab breakdown and would even let you compare memory usage between browsers. If you have some automated test scenarios set up (or are willing to navigate through 100 pages manually), such profiling will tell you if there's something majorly wrong with your website.

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 different thing to take care of :

-memory usage

-memory leaks

For long-running webapps, memory leaks should be absolutely avoided, otherwise users will experience browser crashes. To monitor memory use, you can download process explorer :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Disable all your browser plugins, and then use your app, and perform repetitive tasks. If memory use raises, you got leaks. IE7 - IE8 do leak much more easily than modern browsers, and are much harder to debug, so it is useful to know what is you minim browser compatibility.

For memory usage, a few thing can help decrease the weight of your app :

- instead of looping through dom elements and attaching event handlers functions, use event delegation. ED is really a golden gun here.
- for IE 7 / 8 var nullification was necessary and I think it still helps for modern browsers(needs some testing). To do so, you need also to name your functions, so that you can remove them from memory. (see pebbl answers for more details on this)
- keep control of the dom size. When nodes are added for a feature, they should also be removed when this feature is not used anymore.
- add to all of your components some teardown() method that handles unloading.

ok, sorry I am a bit too quick here, but it would be nice to know :

1. what is your minimum browser
2. if you have detected leaks
3. if ED is a sufficient solution (often it is)