# is it possible to count an object as a "whole"?

Tags: javascript

can i count an objects? like:

```
 var student1 = new Student();
student1.name("ziv");
student1.age();
student1.where("a");


 var student2 = new Student();
student2.name("dani");
student2.age();
student2.where("b");

 var student3 = new Student();
student3.name("bari");
student3.age();
student3.where("c");
```

some function that will count them and return 3 .

thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like a "static" variable implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: You should be using an array if you're going to have several similar variables, and arrays have a `length` property.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean counting *instances*. You'll have to track the instances, e.g. using an array

```
var students = [];
var student1 = new Student()
   ,student2 = new Student();
students.push(students1,students2);
/* later ... */
var nOfStudents = students.length; //=> 2
```

Another idea would be to add a counter to the `Student` prototype:

```
Student.prototype.instanceCnt = 0;
```

And increment it in the Student constructor for every instance

```
   //in the Student constructor function
   function Student(){
     this.instanceCnt += 1;
     /* ... */
   }
   // usage example
   var student1 = new Student()
      ,student2 = new Student()
      ,students = student1.instanceCnt; //=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you would manually need to add a counter in the `Student` constructor or append each instance to an array and get the length of that array.

F.ex:

```
var counter;
function Student() {
    counter++; // this will increase every time Student is initialized
    // continue the constructor...
}
```

Or:

```
var students = [];
function Student() {
    students.push(this); // this will hold the instance in an array
    // continue the constructor...
}
console.log(students.length);
```

Comment: I think the first method is better, because the second one will hold a reference to every Student object ever created and so does not allow the Garbage Collector to free Student objects not used anymore by the actual code. Also, a minor drawback of both methods is that they use a global variable.

Comment: @Ridcully One probably should not worry about the garbage collector in Javascript, and the global variable issue can be removed by using a closure.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Why not worry about the garbage collector? You can run out of memory in javascript as easy as in any other language can't you?

Comment: @Ridcully Maybe, but Javascript doesn't have accessible facilities for memory management.

Comment: @Ridcully "The main purpose of garbage collection is to allow the programmer *not* to worry about memory management of the objects they create and use" — http://stackoverflow.com/a/864544/344643

Comment: @WaleedKhan That's true, still you should not knowingly create memory leaks, even in Javascript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection/864544#864549 And that's the last I'll say to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

there is no concept of statics in Javascript, but you can use closures to emulate that functionality.

```
(function(){

  var numberOfInstances = 0;

  var Student = function(studentName){
    var name = '';

    var _init(){
      name = studentName ? studentName : 'No Name Provided';
      numberOfInstances++;    
    }();

    this.getName = function(){
       return name;
    }; 

    this.getNumberOfInstances = function(){
      return numberOfInstances;
    };

    return this;
  };
})(); 

var student1 = new Student("steve");
var student2 = new Student("sally");
console.log("my name is " + student1.getName());
console.log("my name is " + student2.getName());
console.log("number of students => " + student1.getNumberOfInstances());  
console.log("number of students => " + student2.getNumberOfInstances());
```

Comment: You never call `_init`, nor execute the closure, nor return `Student` from it.

Comment: @WaleedKhan was editing.  init is self invoking, and I return this

Comment: oh right, my outer anonymous function is not self-invoking.  good catch

Comment: The other thing `var _init = function()...` I think.

Comment: ...and non of the statements are terminated.

Comment: @Fraser _none_ of the statements?

Comment: Well half are and half aren't, the code reads like badly punctuated English, with every other sentence missing it's full stop.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple generic Instantiation/Inheritance helper which keeps track of its instances in an Array

Something like this might do it

```
var base = (function baseConstructor() {

  var obj = {
    create:function instantiation() {
        if(this != base) {
        var instance = Object.create(this.pub);
         this.init.apply(instance,arguments);
         this.instances.push(instance);
        return instance;
        } else {
          throw new Error("You can't create instances of base");
        }
    },
    inherit:function inheritation() {
      var sub = Object.create(this);
      sub.pub = Object.create(this.pub);
      sub.sup = this;
      return sub;
    },
    initclosure:function initiation() {},
    instances: [],
    pub: {}

  };



  Object.defineProperty(obj,"init",{
   set:function (fn) {
     if (typeof fn != "function")
       throw new Error("init has to be a function");
     if (!this.hasOwnProperty("initclosure"))      
       this.initclosure = fn;
    },
    get:function () {
        var that = this;
        //console.log(that)
            return function() {
              if(that.pub.isPrototypeOf(this)) //!(obj.isPrototypeOf(this) || that == this))
                that.initclosure.apply(this,arguments);
              else
                throw new Error("init can't be called directly"); 
             };
    }    

  });


  Object.defineProperty(obj,"create",{configurable:false,writable:false});
    Object.defineProperty(obj,"inherit",{configurable:false,writable:false});
  return obj;
})();

var Student = base.inherit()
    Student.init = function (age) {
    this.age = age;    
    }

var student1 = Student.create(21)
var student2 = Student.create(19)
var student3 = Student.create(24)

    console.log(Student.instances.length) // 3
```

Heres an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ififuc/1/edit)