# Does a scope terminate when no references are returned?

Tags: javascript

Take for example this code:

```
var test = (function(){
  var name = 'rar';
  return function foo(){
    console.log('test');
  };
}());
```

`foo` gets returned to `test` *without any references* to `name` in the inner scope. What happens to `name`? Is it destroyed? Or does it continue to exist and dangle with the returned function, but just can't be accessed? Would the first case be similar to doing the following, as if `name` was never part of the equation?:

```
var test = function foo(){
  console.log('test');
};
```

Here's another case:

```
var test2 = (function(){
  var name = 'rar';
  var age = '20';
  return function foo(){
    console.log(age);
  };
}());
```

`age` gets referenced by `foo` and will form a closure. However, `name` still isn't referenced by anything. What happens to `name` in this case? Is it destroyed? Or does it continue to exist and dangle with the returned function, but just can't be accessed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/864549/2269749

Comment: @CORRUPT The answers seem to indicate that what happens depends on the implementation. So that means, in the worst case, `name` will stay, is it right?

Comment: Yes. Browsers have different JS GC engines, each may act differently in this case. Consider `name = null` as an option, to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: `name = null;` might be done before scope ends. Should remove problems.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer You might already know, but I think it's still worthwhile to point out that you can easily inspect a function's closure scope in chrome's dev tools and firefox's firebug.

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome, `name` will be GCed; in FireFox, `name` is kept with the entire closure. IE? I don't know.

Comment: Can I request for a reference as to why Chrome GCs `name` but not in Firefox?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I don't have any reference, my answer is solely based on observation while working with browsers.