# problems with grids with same stores Ext JS

Tags: extjs, store

So I have `panel` (lets call it `fooPanel`) containing a `grid` (lets call if `fooGrid`, which has some `store`). `fooPanel` can be inserted into some `tabpanel`. So the thing is that, it is possible for `tabpanel` to contain two (or more) instances of the `fooPanel`, with some distinct parameters. I think the problem is obvious here. since the `fooGrids` that are withing the panel have the same `stores`, as soon as I reload one store, both `fooGrids` are being reloaded. (since they have same `stores`). Is there a solution to this? Or should I limit the user to just opening one instance of `fooPanel` per `tabpanel`

Comment: Is there any reason that you need more instances? If so just change the store for each instance

Comment: yea there is a reason. how can I 'change the store for each instance' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No easy solution except creating one store per grid. If the reason why you don't want to create multiple instances of the store is to avoid multiple loading, you could hack some sort of caching at the proxy level.

**Edit** Example of how to create multiple store for your grids

You can create the store instance (i.e. use `Ext.create('My.Store')`) yourself in the `initComponent` method of you grid:

```
Ext.define('My.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store'
    ,fields: ['name']
    ,proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
        ,reader: 'array'
    }
    ,data: [['Foo'],['Bar'],['Baz']]
});

Ext.define('My.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

    ,columns: [{dataIndex: 'name'}]

    ,initComponent: function() {
        // /!\ Do that BEFORE calling parent method
        if (!this.store) {
            this.store = Ext.create('My.Store');
        }

        // ... but don't forget to call parent method            
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

// Then I can create multiple grids, they will have their own store instances

Ext.create('My.Grid', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,height: 200
});

Ext.create('My.Grid', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,height: 200
});
```

Or you can specify a new store instance *at creation time*:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,height: 200
    ,columns: [{dataIndex: 'name'}]
    ,store: Ext.create('My.Store') // one instance
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,height: 200
    ,columns: [{dataIndex: 'name'}]
    ,store: Ext.create('My.Store') // two instances!
});
```

But, as far as I'm concerned, I generally don't bother creating full store definitions. I configure the proxy in the model, and use inline store configuration using that model (inline configurations will be turned into their own instances, in Ext4). Example:

```
Ext.define('My.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

    ,columns: [{dataIndex: 'name'}]

    // inline store configuration
    ,store: {
        // The model takes care of the fields & proxy definition
        model: 'My.Model'

        // other params (like remoteSort, etc.)
    }
});

// Now I can create plenty of My.Grid again, that won't interfere with each other
```

Comment: Grid has a property store right? And each panel I instantiate will have the instance of same grid which itself will have same store. Can I have different instances of same stores for different instances of same grid. Data to stores are delivered by ASP.NET in JSON Format. Can you provide some code that shows the example of creating different instances of stores for different instances of grid?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that. I've added some examples in my answer, I hope one will match your use case.

Comment: @rixo Thanks for the inline store suggestion--that seems like a much better way to do this.

Comment: +1 ..Question for you guys.. if a person navigates away from the view that contains the grid(s), how do you remove them so they don't take up memory (is that the right word for browser or JS storage?)?

Comment: @MacGyver Grossly knowing how a [garbage collector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/864516/1387519) works help with this kind of questions. The [destroy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-destroy) method of components should do the work to let the garbage collector kick in, and it is [called by default](http://tinyurl.com/omwf5v9) when components are removed. To build solid confidence about that, you're better off [reading the code](http://tinyurl.com/qbooc27). Inheritance, mixins et al. make it a tad more complex in Ext 4+ though.

Answer (score 2):

In ExtJS 5, you can take advantage of Chained Stores.  That way you can have a single source store, and other stores looking at that same store with different filters.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/whats_new/5.0/whats_new.html

http://extjs.eu/on-chained-stores/

Answer (score 1):

This post might help you

```
Ext.define('App.store.MyStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias  : 'store.app-mystore', // create store alias

    // ... 
}); 

Ext.define('App.view.MyCombo', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    xtype  : 'app-mycombo',

   requires : [
       'App.store.myStore'
   ],

   // combo config
   store : {
       type : 'app-mystore' // store alias; type creates new instance
   }
});
```

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284388-ExtJs-4.2-Multiple-instances-of-the-same-Store&p=1040251