# Destroying sprites in Phaser

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, phaser-framework

I'm having trouble destroying Sprites in Phaser.

I have a JavaScript object, let's call it Block. Block has a sprite property, that gets set like so:

```
this.sprite = this.game.add.sprite(this.x, this.y, 'blocks', this.color);
```

At a certain point in my code, Block is referenced by two different arrays:

```
square[0] = Block;
destroy[0] = Block;
```

On a certain Update() cycle, I need to destroy the sprite, so I'm using the following code:

```
square[0].sprite.destroy(true); //Destroy the sprite.
square[0] = null; //Remove the reference.
```

On the next Update() cycle, when I look at destroy[0], I would expect to see:

```
destroy[0].sprite: null
```

However what I'm seeing is:

```
destroy[0].sprite: b.Sprite
```

With the properties just defaulted and set to false. My worry is, if I were to now set destroy[0] to null, what will happen to that sprite object?

Will it just float around or will it get cleaned up automatically?
Should I be destroying the Block object first in some way?
Also, if destroy() is not nulling the reference, how is it different from kill()?

Any thoughts on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The garbage collector will clean it up if there is no reference to it.

Comment: If you've found what you were looking for, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Difference between Kill and Destroy**

`Kill` is supposed to halt rendering, but the object still exists. It is good if you want to make a reusable object.
You could create the object again without the cost of actually creating the object again.

`Destroy` should remove the object and everything related to it. You use this when you want to send the object to the garbage collector.

Please note that for some objects like text, you can't use `kill`, you can only use `destroy`

Reference:
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1721-how-to-remove-text/#entry12347

Answer (score 4):

@ibnu is correct. [`Destroy`](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/dd39f9ab08d57fa1bacd1287ccadb03fb3151267/src/gameobjects/components/Destroy.js) nukes the object, while `kill` halts rendering. However, your question is relating to memory leaks and GC. I'm no GC pro, but here's what I think is happening.

```
//create an object
this.sprite = this.game.add.sprite(this.x, this.y, 'blocks', this.color);
//create additional references to the object
square[0] = Block;
destroy[0] = Block;
//destroy the object via Phaser's call. Remove 1/2 reference
square[0].sprite.destroy(true); //Destroy the sprite.
square[0] = null; //Remove the reference.
```

But `destroy[0].sprite` still holds a reference to your "destroyed" sprite. `this.sprite` probably does too. That's because the Phaser destroy method only removes Phaser specific properties from the object. [JS is in charge of generic object Garbage Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management). The object is escaping that because you still have valid references in scope.

Fix this problem by removing the reference from scope `destroy[0].sprite = null` or by waiting for the next state to change the scope (assuming destroy is not a static var). You do not have to manage memory resources youself, JS != C. Just make sure you don't [leak](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/) variables across difference scopes.

[What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection) (though I don't think the `delete` command is recommended for GC anymore, it's certainly not necessary in Phaser)