# Knockout Redefine observable - memory leaks?

Tags: knockout.js, memory-leaks, observable

Theorical question

Let's say I hava a variable "test", which is defined as observable:

```
var test = ko.observable("start");
```

Some code after, I call some times a function which does:

```
test = ko.observable("pass n");
```

The former observable is destroyed each time a new one is associated to test, or it leaks memory? 
Note: i understand that the second code should do

```
test("pass n");
```

I am just curious.

And what about redefining test with var, like in first row?

Answer (score 2):

How this precisely works depends on the actual implementation of JavaScript, specifically the way it does garbage collection. You ask a short and seemingly simple question, when in fact this is a very complicated topic. Check [out this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/864516/419956) to see the tip of this ice berg.

However, a short short version, AFAIK, if you have in general this kind of code:

```
var test = ko.observable("abc");
test = ko.observable("xyz");
```

Then there will probably be no reference to the result of `ko.observable("abc")` anymore, and that observable will be subject to garbage collection.

Knockout doesn't have too much to do with that simplified example. Things may get a lot trickier if you have subscriptions flying around, etc. If you want to know more about that you'll need to either ask a way more specific, concrete question, or perhaps in general read up about KO and memory issues. [This blog post by RP Niemeyer](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/10/knockout-cleaning-up.html) is a good start.