# jQuery garbage collect element

Tags: jquery, garbage-collection

I pulling html from another page to grab some `li` elements from it.

Will `$(response)` get garbage collected?

```
function onResponse(response){
    var $keep = $(response).find(".results li").clone();
    items.push($keep);
    $target.append($keep);
}
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/fuzino/edit?js,output)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: I don't think standard GC applies because $(response) may have additional GC consequences, not immediately obvious. (e.g. ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#10 implies I have to `.remove()` for garbage collection to take place, but do i even need that since I haven't yet done an append?)