# Will GC clear removed element variable referenced in its listener?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Garbage Collector won't clear removed from DOM element if it has some reference in code. But what if this reference is inside attached to this element listener?

```
<span id="element">aga</span>
<script>
    function attach() {
        var element = document.getElementById("element");
        element.addEventListener("click", function() {
            //1) if element isn't used in this function
            console.log('aga');
            //2) if element is used in this function
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
    attach();

    document.body.innerHTML = '';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If garbage collection is "properly" implemented by the browser (in particular if it uses [Mark-and-sweep algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm)), that DOM element should be collected, as it is now **unreachable from global scope**.

Your question is probably related to the cyclic reference leading to potential memory leak when the GC implementation uses just a reference counting algorithm. Refer to the above link for more details.

You may also be interested in this post: [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)