# Garbage collection of linked objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var o = (function() {
    var o1 = {name: "o1"};
    var o2 = {name: "o2"};
    var o3 = {name: "o3"};

    o1.child = o2;
    o2.child = o3;
    o3.parent = o2;

    setTimeout(function() {
        o1.child = null;
    }, 1000);

    return o1;
})();
```

Are objects `o2` and `o3` eligible for garbage collection after timeout callback exits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code running in a function, the local variables will be out of scope and the objects pointed to will be available for garbage collection after the timeout fires and breaks the chain linking them, so only `o1` will remain, as assigned to `o`.

If however you just had the contents of the function running in the global scope, eg:

```
var o1 = {name: "o1"};
var o2 = {name: "o2"};
var o3 = {name: "o3"};

o1.child = o2;
o2.child = o3;

setTimeout(function() {
    o1.child = null;
}, 1000);
```

then `o1`, `o2` and `o3` will all be properties of the global object (`window` in browsers) and would need to be cleared individually.

Comment: @Maximus That's changed the scope of the question somewhat... you should generally avoid edits like that

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, the example wasn't correct. The current one is correct. Can you answer based on the new example?

Comment: _all the local variables will be out of scope and available for garbage collection_ - the problem here is that `o1` has reference to `o2` through its child property, that what concerns me.

Comment: @Maximus By setting `o1.child` to `null`, you're breaking that chain though?

Comment: yes, just wanted to make sure you've seen that :) because that's the gist of the question, not whether variables are eligible for gc when function exists :)

Comment: @Maximus Note I said they're eligible for collection when the timeout fires, not when the function exits

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom Garbage collection [absolutely exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection) in modern JS engines.  See also [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection).

Comment: one more clarification, since js uses `nongenerational mark-and-sweep garbage collector` the objects will be eligible for gc even if they had circular reference to each other like in my updated code, correct?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, they'll still be eligible as there are no other references to them.  Note however that different JS engines (or even different versions of the same engine) could easily use different GC implementations.

Comment: I see, thanks) Wondering why I got two downvotes) Is this silly question?

Comment: @Maximus No idea - seems a perfectly valid Q to me!

Comment: @Maximus Perhaps clarify the "within 1 second" bit - do you mean are they eligible before the timeout is up because the variables drop out of scope or are you asking if they're eligible after the timeout has expired?  (either way the answer is "after the timeout is up", as in my answer)

Comment: yeah, clarified that