# When is this scope/closure being garbage collected in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

I am doing a course which is going through scope/closures and briefly mentions garbage collection. During the course a question is posed:

> How long does the scope stay around? And the answer was—until
>   there's no longer any references to it. Yep, so what we basically said
>   was, a closure is kind of like a reference to a hidden scope object.
>   So as long as there's some function that still has a closure over the
>   scope, that scope's going to stay around. But as soon as that closure
>   goes away, scope can get garbage collected. "

```
var sum = function sumHndlr(x, y) {
    if (y !== undefined) {
        return x + y;
    } else {
        return function(y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

So to me, the reference to the closure is when we assigned the function to the `sum` variable, but won't that mean it lasts forever or am I not understanding the way the js will execute in regards to the compiler parser etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by "forever"? Yes, the closure will last as long as `sum`, but that's not forever...

Comment: Well maybe I need more clarification of what's actually happening with garbage collection. Because currently I am thinking of garbage collection like when you'd remove an event listener. Maybe you can explain why it's not forever. Thanks!

Comment: `sum`/`sumHndlr` is no closure. You have to call it (without `y`) to get one. And then that one will stay around (along with the `x` it closes over) as long as you keep it somewhere. Show us that call if you want us to tell more.

Comment: Right— I thought that was right. The inner function is the function which is remembering it's lexical scope. I guess I am not getting how would that go away? To me I am thinking that would happen if you assigned `sum` to `null` or something. But now I am guessing.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz: The reference from the function to the scope never goes away. The scope can only be garbage collected when all functions pointing to it are as well. If you did `var add2 = sum(2);`, then assigning `add2 = null` will make the function eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very briefly, garbage collection is a background process of the Javascript interpreter / virtual machine that automatically frees the memory of objects no longer needed by your program.

For example, since you think of it for event listeners: when you remove an event listener (a function usually) from some event dispatcher, it is likely that no other part of the program will have a reference to the event listener. Therefore, the garbage collector can and will (at some unknown time) free the memory that was taken by the event listener.

Since a closure references a scope object, in order to garbage-collect a closure it needs not only be unreferenced, but also the scope.

If I modify a bit your example:

```
/* some stuff ... */
function add10(a) {
  var adder = function (x) {
     return function(y) {
       return x + y;
     }
  }

  var sum = adder(10); //creates a closure
  return sum(a);
}

var thirty = add10(20);

/* Some more stuff ... */
```

After `add10` is called, even though the program continues to execute some more stuff, the garbage collector can free the memory associated to the closure `sum`, because it is no longer referenced, **nor** is the scope associated to it.

Whereas in this example:

```
/* some stuff ... */
function add10AndGet20Adder(a) {
  var adders = function (x, y) {
     return [function(z) {
       return x + z;
     }, function(z) {
       return y + z;
     }]
  }

  var sums = adders(10, 20); //creates a closure
  return [sums[0](a), sums[1]];
}

var result = add10AndGet20Adder(50);
var sixty = result[0];
var add20 = result[1];

/* Some more stuff ... */
```

When executing some more stuff, `sums[0]` is no longer referenced, **BUT** `add20` (`sums[1]`) still has a reference to the scope that references `x` and`y`, therefore none of the two closures in `sums` can be freed by the garbage collector, until `add20` is referenced by the program.

I hope this makes it clearer, even though the examples are of course nowhere close to real code. In practice, you need to worry about this only if you develop a long-lived program (such as a single page application or nodeJS server) with complicated usage of closures. Otherwise, the memory usage of the closures is unlikely to be a problem.

This SO question gives more details about Javascript garbage collection: [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation using that unique form of a function (the second one) - well maybe unique to me because I've never seen it ;) I am also going to check out the JS garbage collection link too! Cheers!