# JavaScript Clear Variables from Memory

Tags: javascript, memory

I am writing code for JS. 
And I need to know how works memory in JS when I remove big Object.

```
var a = new Object();
a.b = new Object();
a.b.c = new Object();
a.b.c.d = new Object(); 

a.b = undefined; // Is it delete a.b.c and a.b.c.d or not?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

Comment: Thank you for information I read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no pointers to an object it will be garbage collected.
Since the only pointer to `a.b.c` was in `a.b`, `a.b.c` will be garbage collected. Same situation with `a.b.c.d`.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript is automatically garbage collected; the object's memory will be reclaimed only if the Garbage Collectior decides to run and the object is eligible for that.

The delete operator or nullify your object ( a.b = undefined; )has nothing to do with directly freeing memory (it only does indirectly via breaking references). See the [memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) page for more details).