# Garbage Collector in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

How GC works in javascript? As I searched in web, GC will occur based on some period and It will have reachable elements.

My doubt is, If I reload the page, What happens to global variables of previous window? will it be deallocated?

Comment: Reloading the page should reset all Javascript state.

Comment: `unloading` kills everything in the current window. It will be deallocated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

Comment: Actually my question is, memory leaks are temporary right? it ll be deallocated when current DOM unloads?

Comment: @Liam Can you reply for this??

Comment: You can try this yourself, open dev tools in your browser and type var i=0;while(true){i++;} in the console this will pollute your memory until you refresh. After which it will be reset, just like any JS variables you create.