# pointing to a new list in javascript, garbage collecting the old

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I have a question about memory and pointers/references in javascript, in particular p5js.

I declare a list at the top of my code:

```
var my_list;
```

then I can access this inside any function as it is "global".

In my main code, I have an eternal loop in which I visualise `my_list`, then calculate a new list `temp_list`. At the end of the loop I want to swap these lists, so that `my_list` points to the newly created `temp_list`. Actually, I also want to free up the memory being used by the previous list as I don't need it any more.

```
repeated_forver(){

// visualise my_list

// calculate temp_list
var temp_list = .. something ...

// point my_list to new data
my_list = temp_list;

}
```

Will this do what I want it to do?

- `my_list` points to the newly calculated data, temporarily help under the name `temp_list`
- garbage collect the data that was previously pointed to by the name `my_list`

Is this how javascript works? My initial research suggested that structures like lists are referred to by name / pointer and this does work.

Comment: It should work like this. We can't control garbage collection but it will do its thing as long the data isn't referenced anymore.

Comment: Thanks @LuizChagasJr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection)

Comment: @LuizChagasJr you can force garbage collection in certain contexts, EG NodeJS and Chrome v8.  Explained further here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/T5caRqaTOo0