# Will the memory which store the old variable be free when reassign the variable in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, lifetime

In the following code

```
a = 1
b = {"a": a} // this output {"a": 1}
a = 2
console.log(b) // this still output {"a": 1}
```

In such situation, will the memory which store the content `1` be free when reassign the variable to 2?

Comment: No, because the `1` is still available, as you can see in `b`. If it went away, the `b` object would break. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173974/what-are-the-result-of-the-mark-and-sweep-in-that-code#comment95176931_54173974 for a similar question

Comment: Check this out as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection

Comment: `a` is a primitive. It's not just a reference to memory, it is a `double` _by value_. Its _value_ is _copied_ to the property `b.a`.

Answer (score 2):

variable did not lose its memory space until it destroyed.

when you write

```
  a = 1
  b = {"a": a}
```

value of a is assigned to **a** node of object **b**. **a** variable is not bind to **a** node. if you want to update node a to new value you can do by:

```
  b.a = 2;        
  console.log(b.a); //will print 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = {"a": a} // this output {"a": 1}
```

this instruction tells the compiler to create a new object and set the key "a" to the same value the variable a has right now, so the value 1 is copied into the memory of b.