# Is the request data garbage collected at the end of the request-reply cycle?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, garbage-collection, gunicorn

I am running a `django` API (`drf`) via `gunicorn`, as a `wsgi` application.

The API is handling sensitive information (passwords and other secrets) which need to be cleared from system memory (`ram`). My understanding is that all the data coming in the API request will be garbage collected using the normal reference counting mechanism: once the request has been processed and gunicorn has received the reply, no more references to the request exist and it will be thus completely garbage collected.

The same will apply to any object created during request processing: all references to it will be removed after the request has been processed.

The only way in that this assumption is broken is if I do any of the following:

1. store references to the request in a global object
2. create cyclical references to the request object

In the case of `2`, the `gc` module will be able to detect the references and remove them. I can even trigger that manually with `gc.collect()`

The first problem can be avoided by simply being careful not to store references in global objects.

I have two questions:

1. Are there other things I should be careful about regarding data persistence in memory?
2. How can I force garbage collection to run (`gc.collect()`) at the end of request processing in `gunicorn`?

Comment: A duplicate type of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594522/django-python-garbage-collection-woes.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on this, but my investigation suggests that.

1: you should be able to use the post_request hook to invoke gc.collect

2: you could set max requests to 1 to always restart the worker thread before each request which would be slow but prevent any data leaking between threads