# Kineticjs - Add grid to canvas

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to introduce a grid function (to add/remove) a grid on a canvas.
I pulled most of the following code:

```
var make_gr

id = function() {
    var grid = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var r = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: W,
        height: H,
        fill: 'transparent'
    });
    grid.add(r);
    for (i = 0; i < w + 1; i++) {
        var I = i * CELL_SIZE;
        var l = new Kinetic.Line({
            stroke: "black",
            points: [I, 0, I, H]
        });
        grid.add(l);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < h + 1; j++) {
        var J = j * CELL_SIZE;
        var l2 = new Kinetic.Line({
            stroke: "black",
            points: [0, J, W, J]
        });
        grid.add(l2);
    }
    stage.add(grid);      
};
```

to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipens/37Z4P/13/), but it doesn't work.  All I want is for a grid to be drawn at the base of the canvas - to allow people to fine tune the positioning of elements on the canvas.  I also want to give the user the ability to remove the grid.  Can anybody see what I have missed?

Many Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button click function is calling `makeGrid()` which is undefined.

Your function is called `make_grid()` so you need to change your click event from:

```
$d("body").on('click','#addGrid',function(){
  makeGrid();
});
```

To:

```
$d("body").on('click','#addGrid',function(){
  make_grid();
});
```

Once you do that, the grid appears. To remove it you can either use `hide()` `remove()` or `destroy()` on the grid layer that you created with `make_grid()`. Since you want to allow the user to hide/show the grid, I recommend using `.hide()`.

**Also note** that you should only add the grid layer to the stage once. I suggest you call `make_grid()` when the stage is initialised, but hide the grid layer. Then with your two buttons just use `.show()` and `.hide()` to make the grid appear and disappear.

More info on `remove` vs `destroy`: [What is the difference between remove and destroy in kinetic.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316918/what-is-the-difference-between-remove-and-destroy-in-kinetic-js)

Comment: Haha, what an error! Yes, I'll call it from initStage and hide it straight away. Thanks for your help!