# KineticJs - Grid not appearing in canvas

Tags: kineticjs

Related to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659288/kineticjs-add-grid-to-canvas)

I have now updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipens/37Z4P/15/) to add the grid only during the initial load.

A few questions relating to this:
1) When I click on "show grid" it doesn't appear. However, if I comment out the `removeGrid()`
line from initStage, the grid does appear. What have I missed - as I am assuming the grid object I am calling in showGrid is different to the one in removeGrid - although I can only see it being created once.

2) I have also added a "clear stage" button, which when called clears the stage (works)
but I am unable to show the grid again. I have included `make_grid();` after clearing the stage - but it has no effect.  I assume due to the error raised in (1)?

3) How can I start the grid 20px in from the top and from the left.  Essentially, I want the grid only to appear in the centre of the canvas - leaving a 20px border all the way around.

Many Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your removeGrid() error is concerned, there was a simple mistake in the jsfiddle:

1. `$d("body").on('click','#removeGrid',function(){` <-- it was '#addGrid' in both the event handlers

It also solves the prob 2.
updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aplus1/37Z4P/20/

For your prob 3: check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aplus1/37Z4P/21/

and here is the relevant code that was changed:

```
for (i = 0; i < (stage.getWidth()-40)/CELL_SIZE + 1; i++) {
    var I = i * CELL_SIZE + 20;
    var l = new Kinetic.Line({
        stroke: "black",
        points: [I, 20, I, stage.getHeight()-20]
    });
    grid.add(l);
}

for (j = 0; j < (stage.getHeight()-40)/CELL_SIZE + 1; j++) {
    var J = j * CELL_SIZE + 20;
    var l2 = new Kinetic.Line({
        stroke: "black",
        points: [20, J, stage.getWidth()-20, J]
    });
    grid.add(l2);
}
```

What is happening here is as follow: I have reduced your loop such that it goes from 20px to Width-20px, offset your end-points by 20px on left/top and reduced 40px from widht/height to get the other end-point

Let me know if you have any questions.