# in javascript, will garbage collector work on cross referenced objects?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am concerned about memory leaks in my client-side javascript application.

in particular, I have objects which cross-reference each other.

```
var obj1 = new SomeObject();
var obj2 = new AnotherObject();
obj1.ref = obj2;
obj2.ref = obj1;
```

as the program runs, `obj1` and `obj2` are reset

```
obj1 = new SomeObject();
obj2 = new AotherObject();
obj1.ref = obj2;
obj2.ref = obj1;
```

the question is whether the original objects which were assigned to `obj1` and `obj2` will be garbage collected<strike>, or do they need to be `delete`d manually</strike>?

Comment: Or to put this another way, will objects with circular references be garbage collected when there are no remaining "external" references? Modern browsers should have no trouble garbage collecting such objects. (Also, you can't `delete` an object per se: you can `delete` an object's property, and if that property was the last reference to some other object then the other object will be garbage collected.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - your wording much better, thanks.  good point on `delete` - what a weird function that is.

Comment: It's fairly easy to write a loop and test this...

Comment: For more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774357/how-does-the-garbage-collection-mechanism-work is also interesting.