# Impact on memory when reference objects are reassigned

Tags: java, memory, reference, garbage-collection

When the `new` keyword is used in java, memory is allocated, but I am confused here:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo(); //consumes memory m1
Foo f2 = new Foo(); //consumes memory m2
f2=f1; //Now, f2 just points to f1, so what about the memory m2
```

Does memory m2 just wait for the GC, as the contents are not copied, both `f2` and `f1` point to the same thing now m1 or m2? Does this cause unused memory until the GC does its thing?

Any explanation, or views on this are welcomed.

Comment: The GC will clean it up if it's no longer needed.  The heap that's allocated still contains the value it was initialized to.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774357/how-does-the-garbage-collection-mechanism-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object previously referenced by `f2` is unreachable, and will wait around in memory until the GC gets around to handling it.

Now *theoretically* it would be possible to have new objects created in that space, as it's not being used anymore. However I don't know of any GC algorithm that would do this kind of "hot swapping", and it would probably be inefficient. The algorithm would become more complex and the advantage in memory use would be minimal. It would still require the "mark" phase to identify objects waiting for collection.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The original object that f2 was referring to will still be on the heap until GC collects it (reclaims the memory occupied by it). So, f2 would reference the same object as f1.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked:

In Java and other languages with garbage collectors, the language support library will reclaim the memory and make it available for reuse.

In the large:
In C++/C and languages that do not typically have garbage collectors, the memory is lost and the process can never recover it.