# How would I get 8 combinations of 4 numbers in java

Tags: java

So I want the numbers 0,1,2,3, and every combination of them in 8 places like from

00000000 to 33333333

I wrote something that technically works but it looks ugly and inefficient, do you guys know a better way, I swear theres something I can do with %10 and checking if its under 4 but I can't picture it.

```
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; i1++) {
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) {
                for(int i3 = 0; i3 < 4; i3++) {
                    for(int i4 = 0; i4 < 4; i4++) {
                        for(int i5 = 0; i5 < 4; i5++) {
                            for(int i6 = 0; i6 < 4; i6++) {
                                for(int i7 = 0; i7 < 4; i7++) {
                                    for(int i8 = 0; i8 < 4; i8++) {
                                        System.out.println("" +((Integer)i1).toString()+((Integer)i2).toString()+((Integer)i3).toString()+((Integer)i4).toString()+((Integer)i5).toString()+((Integer)i6).toString()+((Integer)i7).toString()+((Integer)i8).toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit:
Thank you for the Base 4 suggestion
This is now my revised code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i<65536;i++){
            String x =Integer.toString(i,4);
            while(x.length() < 8){
                x = "0" + x;
            }
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        
    }
```

Edit 2: I made the while loop wrong where I would have doubles of some digits, and none of others, so I fixed it in the code above

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as printing every base 4 number from 0 to 65535(base 10)? And if it is, then you could do it with one for loop and a printing function that could render numbers in base 4 form?

Comment: Thank you!! That was it, ill edit in that I got it

Answer (score 3):

You could just loop from 0 to 33333333, printing only numbers for which only 0, 1, 2 and 3 digits appear inside the number:

```java
int high = 33;   // replace with 33333333 for your actual example
int width = 3;   // replace with 8 for your actual example
String mask = "%0" + width + "d";

for (int i=0; i <= high; ++i) {
    boolean print = true;
    int num = i;
    while (num > 0) {
        if (num % 10 != 0 && num % 10 != 1 && num % 10 != 2 && num % 10 != 3) {
            print = false;
            break;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }

    if (print) {
        System.out.println(String.format(mask, i));
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
000
001
002
003
010
011
012
013
020
021
022
023
030
031
032
033
```

Comment: dont you think this is method would be more inefficient

Comment: Method 1(Original) : -
Count :- 65536
nanoTime Diff :- 1109677

Method 2(Answer) : -
Count :- 33333334
nanoTime Diff:- 167496707

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another (I guess inefficient) way to do this, you can write a permute function that recursively generates string permutations like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        permute("", stringList);
    }

    private static void permute(String res, List<String> resultList) {
        if (res.length() == 8) {
            resultList.add(res);
            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
            permute(res + i, resultList);
        }
    }
```

Now `stringList` will hold all the permutations. However, this method creates many intermediary strings, so writing this just to give an idea of how it can be done recursively as well.

**Using `StringBuilder`:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        permute(new StringBuilder(""), stringList);
    }

    private static void permute(StringBuilder sb, List<String> resultList) {
        if (sb.length() == 8) {
            resultList.add(sb.toString());
            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
            sb.append(i);
            permute(sb, resultList);
            sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for this:

```java
public void combinations(int current,int depth){
    current*=10;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        current++;
        if(depth==0){
            System.out.println(current);
        }else{
            combinations(current,depth-1);
        }
    }
}

//when you want to calculate it
combinations(0,7);
```

This method is efficient as it only calculates the values you need and you don't need to store unnecessary values and do not need to create Strings by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your modified code can be made a bit more efficient.

Since Java has no lpad function, you can mimic it with a string array containing the pad appropriate for a given length. This has the benefit of reducing [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/774487/1707353).

```
public class TenFourGB {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      String pads[] = {"00000000","0000000","000000","00000","0000","000","00","0",""};
      for (int i=0; i<65536; i++){
         String x = Integer.toString(i, 4);
         System.out.print(pads[x.length()]); // pads length is coupled to i's max value
         System.out.println(x);
      }   
   }
}
```

This solution's timing (>> /dev/null):

```
real    0m0.397s
real    0m0.229s
real    0m0.228s
real    0m0.235s
real    0m0.232s
```

Tim's solution* timing (>> /dev/null):

```
real    0m0.423s
real    0m0.443s
real    0m0.612s
real    0m0.461s
real    0m0.426s
```

I had to modify `high` and `width` in Tim's code to make it emit the same numbers as mine, thereby making it a fair race.